# Importing dictionaries from a file in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I'm trying to make a bot in Python to manage some tasks on twitter using tweepy.

I'm saving the credentials for auth in several files but I want one file only. Here is an example:

```
for x in range(0, 3):

  if x == 0 : from keysaccount1 import keys
  if x == 1 : from keysaccount2 import keys
  if x == 2 : from keysaccount3 import keys
  if x == 3 : from keysaccount4 import keys

  CONSUMER_KEY = keys['consumer_key']
  CONSUMER_SECRET = keys['consumer_secret']
  ACCESS_TOKEN = keys['access_token']
  ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = keys['access_token_secret']

  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
  auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
  api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

The file on which the data are stored is in this format, for example keysaccount1 :

```
keys = dict(
    consumer_key =          'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    consumer_secret =       'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    access_token =          'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    access_token_secret =   'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
)
```

Is there a way to save all this on the same file, as I have the x variable on the cycle that I could use to choose which account I'm managing?

Comment: How about making a list storing all your `key`s, i.e. `keys_list = [keys1, keys2, ...]` and then replace your if stuff by `keys_list[x]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single dictionary:

```
auth_data = {
    0: {
        'consumer_key': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'consumer_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'access_token': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'access_token_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       }
    ...
```

You can access particular fields like this then:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    keyset = auth_data[x]

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keyset['consumer_key'], keyset['consumer_secret'])
    auth.set_access_token(keyset['access_token'], keyset['access_token_secret'])
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

To save the data, you can just use the python module pickle:

```
import pickle

def read():
    with open('data/keys.p', 'r') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

def write(data): 
    with open('data/keys.p', 'w+') as f:
        return pickle.dump(f, data)

# Read data

auth_data = read()

# Write data

write(auth_data)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!! :D

Comment: @RogerioCaeiro Perfect! Let me know if there's something else that you need! Feel free to also accept the answer :)